# bootstrap-select with JQuery slimscroll display error

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, bootstrap-select

I'm currently using [boostrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) 1.12.2 plugin to display some filter widgets. Thoses widgets are displayed on the left side of the page, and are dynamically added. The widget list can be quite long (20+ filters) so I display them in a scrollable div, using [JQuery slimScroll](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll) 1.3.8. 
It works fine when options in selectpicker are small, however when options are long, they aren't displayed correctly :

[image]

whereas I would like to have this (obtained when slimScroll is disabled) :

[image]

I guess this is just some css overflow issue, but I can't find a way to fix this... 
Here is a pen demonstrating the issue: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdZLbE)

html :

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: powderblue;">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <button type="button" onclick="loadWidget();">load</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="content">
          <div id="parent"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#content').slimScroll({
  height: '550px'
});

function loadWidget() {

  var options = '<option value="0">very long option text that doesnt fit in selectpicker</option><option value="1">yet another option</option>';

  var html = '<div class="form-group "><label for="SQ">randomLabel</label><div class="form-input"><select id="SQ" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" >' + options + '</select></div></div>';

  $('#parent').html(html);
  $('#SQ').selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `container` option and setting it to `body`:

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#container

> Append the select to a specific element, e.g. `container: 'body'` or `data-container=".main-content"`

This might fix the problem, but I haven't tested it. I don't know how it will behave with jQuery-slimScroll. I also found this issue that might help:

https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/1552

> The menu needs to be told when to update its position. The plugin automatically detects when the window is scrolled/resized. So, I recommend something like:
>
> ```
> $('#grid').on('scroll', function() {
>     $(window).scroll();
> });
> ```

Comment: The `container` option worked just fine, thanks a lot for you answer!

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have to partitions and in first partition you have an input and below that the suggetion box if you want it to over lap to the second partition then you have to make the position `absolute` of the suggetion box with highest `z-index` in css.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I already tried providing a higher z-index (on select, div or button) but it doen't work

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to fix it (tested in both Chrome and Firefox).

```
#content{
  margin-left:0px;
}
.container-fluid > div{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: for me it only fixes the left-size, but the right side is still not displayed correctly (in both chrome and firefox), see teh updated codepen

Comment: See my edit or this demo http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/WRqamR seems to work

Comment: But I can't remove the `<div class="col-md-3">`, otherwise the rest of the page won't be displayed correctly... I need to keep the bootstrap grid system, this is the whole point of this question :p

Comment: Still not, I've updated the pen to make it clearer: the red div has to be visible!

Comment: It's visible to me, at the right of the select element. In both browsers. What browser do you use?

Comment: I'm using firefox 51, but I need to keep the red div inthe right side visible, see the updated pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdZLbE

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. It's visible to me (firefox 51) see https://postimg.org/image/phusx3ibb/

Comment: ok, looks like this is dependant on screen size (mine is 1280x1024)

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to put select widget inside slim scroll div , slim scroll is adding overflow:hidden if you remove it the div will be not scrollable

[here an updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWyMEz?editors=1010)

```
      <div class="row" id="content">
          <div id="parent"></div>
          <div id="scrollable">
          <p>text </p>
          <p>text </p>
          <p>text </p>
          <p>text </p>
          <p>text </p>
          <p>text </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but the 'parent' div has to be to be in the SlimScrollDiv, so this wont't work...