# Issues with Flexbox parent calculating width without overflow: hidden

Tags: html, reactjs, css, flexbox

Basically, I want to implement a reusable library in React that takes a list of components and displays them as a flex container. When the component mounts, or when the user resizes the window, the component recalculates its width and if the sum of its children exceeds its own width, it will hide the excess children and append a button to the end of the list that displays the excess children in a vertical dropdown. The component is given a prop that defines its minimum width, but otherwise it calculates its width by reference to the flex dom node containing all children elements. It itself is also a flex item whose flex property is `1 0 <value of minWidth property>`.

The crux of the issue is that everything works beautifully if I add `overflow: hidden` to the flex container. As the user resizes the window, the size will recalculate from X all the way to the provided min width. Without overflow: hidden, however, its width has a floor equal to the sum of its children. You can observe this in the demo below. If you open devtools and resize the window, you will see the clientWidth value of the left and right containers (which would each be a separate instance of the component described above). The intended behavior would be that as the window is resized smaller, the left and right container would shrink to 200 and and 300px respectively, during which I would be able to calculate the number of children to hide in each (1 in the left, and 1 and then eventually 2 in the right container). If you uncomment out line 9 in the codepen scss file, you can observe this exact behavior.

The reason `overflow: hidden` is not a viable solution is that in some cases, one or more of the children components will render a sub-component such as a dropdown/date-picker component that will then be hidden because of the parent's `overflow: hidden`. In the cases that I wish to use this, the sub-component is absolutely positioned (and anchored to the child component), and thus would not affect the width of the child components in respect to the parent flex container.

I can think of a few solutions that would involve tinkering with the child components themselves (using solutions involving `position: fixed`, etC), but as this is intended to be a reusable library which simply takes a list of components to display, I would like to keep the fix to the parent container if possible.

**.js file**

```
const left = document.querySelector('.left');

const right = document.querySelector('.right');

const handleWindowResize = event => {
  console.log('left: ', left.clientWidth);
  console.log('right: ', right.clientWidth);
};

window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
```

**.scss file**

```
.toolbar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left, .right {
  display: flex;
  // overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  flex: 1 0 200px;

}

.right {
  flex: 1 0 300px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

**.html file**

```
<div class='toolbar'>
  <div class='left'>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EezbZO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason `overflow: hidden` is not a viable solution is that in some
>   cases, one or more of the children components will render a
>   sub-component such as a dropdown/date-picker component that will then
>   be hidden because of the parent's `overflow: hidden`. In the cases
>   that I wish to use this, the sub-component is absolutely positioned
>   (and anchored to the child component)...

This is a well known problem, commonly seen with modals. In your situation, you basically have to use `overflow: hidden`. There's probably no other choice.

Robust "dropdown/datepicker"-based libraries will commonly provide an "escape hatch" option that will allow you to append the dropdown part to a chosen element, commonly `body`. If a library doesn't have it yet, it's usually because nobody complained about it yet.

To drive my point home, here are some examples:

- React Select: https://react-select.com/advanced#portaling

  > React-select exposes a `menuPortalTarget` prop, that lets you portal
  >   the select menu to a dom node of your choosing.
- react-dates: [example](http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?selectedKind=DRP%20-%20Calendar%20Props&selectedStory=appended%20to%20body%20%28in%20scrollable%20container%29&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel)
- A random old [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42637778/405015)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I ended up finding a satisfactory result by using css-grid instead of flexbox (even though flexbox is generally better for one-dimension layouts).

[Modified demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOoYpG)

Comment: You're welcome. Note that in the modified demo, if you make your window width narrow enough, some of the children (can still) escape from the container (horizontal scrollbar appears). I don't know if that matters for your use case.